# Thymeleaf passando 2 parâmetros para URL

Tags: html, url, parâmetros, paginação, thymeleaf

Boa noite pessoal,

Estou com o seguinte problema:

Estou tentando passar 2 parâmetros na URL utilizando o Thymeleaf, porém não estou conseguinto recuperar o valor da variável "nome" para passar no segundo parâmetro.

Obs.: Euconsigo passar o número da página.

Por gentileza, poderiam me ajudar?

Controller:

```
@GetMapping("/listar")
public String listar(@RequestParam(name = "nome", defaultValue = "") String nome,
        @RequestParam(name = "page", defaultValue = "0") int page, ModelMap model) {
    if (!nome.isEmpty()) {
        model.addAttribute("produtos", produtoService.findByNome(PageRequest.of(page, 5), nome));
        model.addAttribute("nome", nome);
    } else {
        model.addAttribute("produtos", produtoService.listarTodos(PageRequest.of(page, 5)));
    }
    model.addAttribute("currentPage", page);
    return "produto/lista";
}
```

HTML que quero passar os parâmetros:

```
<ul class="pagination" style="text-align: center">
    <li class="waves-effect"
        th:each="i: ${#numbers.sequence(0, produtos.totalPages-1)}"><a
        th:href="@{/produtos/listar/(page=${i}, nome=${nome})}"
        th:text="${i}"
        th:classappend="${currentPage}==${i}?'button_actions_back':''"></a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

consegui resolver o problema.

A montagem da URL estava errada. O correto seria:

```
th:href="@{/produtos/listar?page=${i}&nome=${nome}}"
```